# "jQuery UI Bootstrap"

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

Recently i came across a project called "jQuery UI Bootstrap", and in the project page it says started to bring the beauty of Twitter Bootstrap to jQuery UI widgets. What does it actually mean?

1. is it a Jquery UI based framework with bootstrap styles?
2. is it a mix of bootstrap UI and Jquery UI widgets?
3. is it a frameworks with responsive features of bootstrap and rich collection of UI widgets of Jquery UI?

if you guys have experience using this framework please share your experience.

appreciate your help

Thanks,
Keth

Comment: Sorry Lister..i have corrected it

Comment: its clearly mention "A Bootstrap-themed kickstart for jQuery UI widgets" ref: http://addyosmani.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/index.html